# New React project, create-react-app, opens to /public/index.html instead of App.js

Tags: reactjs, react-native, create-react-app

I'm new to react, and am trying to get several tutorials to work. 
These are the steps I've followed:
 
C:\React-App>*npm install -g create-react-app*
C:\React-App>*npx create-react-app my-app*
C:\React-App>*cd my-app*
C:\React-App\my-app>*npm run build*
C:\React-App\my-app>*npm start*

When I open http://localhost:3000/ in my browser, I get a white page, and when I look at the source, I see the source from /public/index.html

All my tutorials show that I should be seeing the code from App.js.

What am I doing wrong?

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

/public/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should wait a little bit, when you run `npm start` it take some time to start.

Look at the console you runned `npm start`, probably there is a message saying that it's starting.

The first time it starts is kind of slow.

## Edit:

Because you are in development mode, webpack won't change your code to be compatible to all browsers, so it works on chrome but not Edge.

Comment: This is what it says in the console, it looks like it started fine.
Starting the development server...
Compiled successfully!

You can now view my-app in the browser.

Comment: @baumli and it's still blank?

Comment: Yes, still blank, I do have an error in my browser console:  HTML1300: Navigation occurred.
localhost:3000 (1,1)

[HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...
0.chunk.js (38870,7)

0: SyntaxError
0.chunk.js (3873,1)

Comment: @baumli could you please share your `index.js` and `App.js` ?

Comment: I posted the steps, I haven't changed any code, this is a new project.

Comment: @baumli  What browser are you using?

Comment: I think the browser was the issue.  Opened it in Chrome and it worked fine.  Edge is what I was initially using.

Comment: @baumli yes, the browser is the problem.